# entity framework POCO + recommended patterns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, poco

We do like EntityFramework (CTP5) quite a lot and Using it along with ASP.NET MVC3.

What I dislike is;
things are mixed in together.

I can place a **DisplayAttribute**, **RequiredAttribute**, **RangeAttribute**, **CompareAttribute** together in the same class which means I am mixin in **database validation**, some **business logic** and **UI** alltogether. I can even place **ScriptIgnore** attribute to customize it as a **Json DTO** object. So I can use the same POCO class for Persistance, Presentation, DTO and Business Object, and as my domian model.

Which design patterns do you follow along with EF POCO + MVC3 toolset. What layers do you have?
What resposibilities do you add to your classes (Is Your POCO class also your Domain Model)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use View Models to solve this problem. Validation and UI presentation attributes go to the view model. In this pattern the controller uses a repository to fetch an EF model, maps this EF model to a view model (I use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for this) and passes the view model to the view. Because the view model contains all the UI presentation attributes the view behaves as expected. Each view must have its own view model. This means that you could have multiple view models associated to the same EF model but contain a different subset of properties and display formatting attributes based on the specific requirements of the view.

The process works the other way around as well: the controller receives a view model from the view as argument. It maps the view model back to a model and passes the EF model to the repository. UI validation attributes are handled on the view model because you could have different validation requirements in different views: think for example Insert/Update views. In the insert view you will be creating a new entity thus the Id property won't be required. You won't even have an Id property on your view model in this case. In the update view on the contrary the Id property will be required.

Comment: does your controller use Repository directly, do you have a Service Layer, to invoke behaviours?

Comment: @hazimdikenli, that will depend on the project I am working on. If I have a complex business logic I would use a service layer. If not and CRUD repository operations are enough to implement what I want I use them directly in the controller without a service layer.

Comment: even in complex projects, you have simple tasks that could result in using a service layer adding extra overhead, what would you do in that case, User generic Services, or use services only on objects which have business logic. Lets say you are using a service to ship an order but Would you use a service to declare new UnitOfMeasurement?

Comment: @hazimdikenli, I don't understand your question.

Comment: In Brief, If you are using a ServiceLayer, do you use it always no matter how simple the task is (like adding a new parameter to a UnitOfMeasurements table)?

Comment: @hazimdikenli, I don't use it always, only on controllers that need it.

Comment: Anyone can point me to a dummy sample three-layer solution (sln)? 
I need to do the same with Windows Forms and I can't figure out what goes where..

Answer (score 3):

My POCO classes are almost always domain models and almost never view models so I don't have these problems.

The best practice is to use special "view model" class when passing data from controller to view (or as JsonResult). In such case you mark UI based attributes in that view model. In most cases (except pure crud applications) you need to display something more or something less then your domain object so you still need some view model (unless you use ViewData directly).

Data annotations on domain object makes sense only if you want to use them for business/data level validation which can take different rules then UI validation.

If you want to follow strict DDD where POCO classes are domain objects = offers methods performing domain logic on instance of object you should go even further because in such case your business facede should not expose domain objects to controller. In such case you will end up with data transfer objects exposed on business facade and consumed in controller. I'm not purist so in this scenario I'm open minded to using data annotations on DTOs directly but it depends on another requirements.

Comment: what do you mean by that last paragraph.

Comment: I mean that if you follow DDD and you create domain object, its methods should be used only in business/domain logic layer. If you expose such object to controller you can call them in presentation layer => violation of that rule.

Comment: thanks for clarification, so in that case, how would you check if an order is shippable or cancellable, return it in the ViewModel as properties?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question - such validation will be performed in business logic by methods on domain object.

Comment: I think that presentation layer objects should be another models -except DDD models-, as name "presentation layer". Suppose that .DataAnnonations works fine for web UI but why we "have" to use .DataAnnonations attributes for mobile UI (such as iPhone)?